# how to upgrade game database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do you guys upgrade your game database?I actually mean add new column to your table, say we got a playerrole table which changes frequently.For some reason,I don't want to login to the database server to upgrade it.I want to write a script file to upgrade it when the game server start.Well, the patch script file looks something like the following one:

```
  drop PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbpatch;
    DELIMITER ;;
    create PROCEDURE dbpatch()
        declare exit HANDLER for SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
        BEGIN
            start TRANSACTION;
            // sql sentence
            update version set v = versionnum;
            commit;
        end;;
    DELIMITER;
    call dbpatch();
    drop PROCEDURE if EXISTS dbpatch;
```

The problem is that alter table statements which I put in dbpatch will end current active transaction and implicit commit according to mysql doc(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html),this might cause partial success and could not be rolled back.For example, I got a table A and I want to add three new columns 'a', 'b', 'c' to this table,but table A already got column 'c'.The patch process will be terminated by sqlexception but column 'a' and 'b' will be added to talbe A.I hope it could be rolled back rather than partial success.Then I googled it, there are some ways to work around,but they tend to create a temporary table to hack it.
This way did not work for me,because I got some records in table,if I do it this way,I have to move records back and forth which is more error-prone.Any idea how to solve it?Any help will be appreciated.Our current mysql version is 5.5.27.